# Select text when editing

Tags: jquery, angularjs, x-editable

I'm editing some users with Angularjs xeditable. I want the text to be selected when I click on an editable element.
I think I know how to write the directive:

```
   UserManager.directive('selectWhenEditing',function(){
        var linkFunction = function(scope,element,attributes)
        {
            console.log(element.find('span'));
            console.log(element.find('.editable'));
            element.find('.editable').on('click',function(){
                element.find('.editable-input').select();
                console.log("launched");
            });
        };
        return{
            restrict: 'A',
            link:linkFunction
        };}
    );
```

This is my caller element:

```
<td data-select-when-editing="">
<span class="ng-scope ng-binding editable editable-click" onbeforesave="checkUsername($data,user)" editable-text="user.username"> Name </span>
</td>
```

It appears that the find() method does not find the class "editable" (but it does find the span for example). Though as you can see in my html code, the class editable is applied to the span so it should be found by the find().

Answer (score 0):

Check this link out and understand it carefully http://jsfiddle.net/mahbub/XRL4U/

```
<a xeditable...></a>
```

Comment: thank you but actually the problem wasn't the directive but the find method which doesn't get me what I want...